# Files accessible only by specific users in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

On my site, users can send files between each other, one on one.

However, I want these files to be accessible only by them. In other words, I don't want those files to end up in a public path.

In this case, I have a table called "comm_uploads". In this table, you have the file path, the send id and the receiver id.

I also have page that lists all the files sent between the two.

On this page you'd have something like...

```
@foreach ($uploads as $upload) 
    <div><a href="LINK TO PRIVATE FILE PATH">{{ $upload->file_name }}</a></div> 
@endforeach
```

How could I make this so those file can only be looked at by those two users?

Comment: you want hide them in view ??? or others can view but restrict to download ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using direct path in the Anchor you can use a route where In the controller you can write the logic you want to check whether file is allowed to access or not and based on that you can either return Unauthorized Error(Error code 401) or you can simply do `return response()->download($pathToFile);`

Eg.

```
if (fileAllowedToAccess()) {
    return response()->download($pathToFile);
} else {
    return abort(401);
}
```

Comment: Ah. I see where you're getting at. However, I'm having trouble retrieving the file. For example, error: "uploads/artistUploads/2/2/c/Azoruk/1493355445_3Yf358A.png" does not exist

Comment: If the file is in storage directory then you can do `storage_path('/uploads/artistUploads/2/2/c/Azoruk/1493355445_3Yf358A.png')` and if the file is in Public directory then you can do `public_path('/uploads/artistUploads/2/2/c/Azoruk/1493355445_3Yf358A.png')` checkout laravel path helpers [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers)